# Specifying gas amount for contract call from JavaScript

Tags: web3js, gas, contract-debugging, contract-invocation, out-of-gas

I'm making this call from JavaScript to the contract function.

```
contracts['CrowdFunder'].contract.contribute({value: web3.toWei(0.000000000000000005, 'ether')});
```

The function is called, but the error message says,

**An error occurred during contract execution: 'Out of gas'**

See  http://testnet.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x58c3e7d41db0dd3ba4c2b600b374b2576f9508d84e7351058232027af4cc3abb

How do I specify the amount of gas in JavaScript for the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing

```
contracts['CrowdFunder'].contract.contribute({
    value: web3.toWei(0.000000000000000005, 'ether')
});
```

to

```
contracts['CrowdFunder'].contract.contribute({
    value: web3.toWei(0.000000000000000005, 'ether'), 
    gas: 100000 
});
```

Refer to the example under Contract Methods in [JavaScript API - web3.eth.contract](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract).

And modifying the call as suggested by `eth`'s comment below:

```
contracts['CrowdFunder'].contract.contribute({
    value: 5, 
    gas: 100000 
});
```

Comment: Also, OP since you only want to pass 5 wei, just use `value: 5`.